# Approximating an unitary matrix to $\mathbb{Z}[i,1/\sqrt2]$ while keeping unitarity

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, diophantine-equations, quantum-computation

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.3200.pdf) (lemma 3) it is claimed that any column of a unitary matrix that has two entries at zero can be approximated to $\mathbb{Z}[i,1/\sqrt2]$ by solving the Diophantine equation $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = n$ (the original unitary is decomposed in several reflections, each one of them corresponding to a column). However, while this process preserves the unit norm of the individual columns, it does not preserve the orthogonality of the original matrix (as far as I could check numerically). Is there a method to approximate an unitary matrix to $\mathbb{Z}[i,1/\sqrt2]$ such that the approximation is also unitary?